# unable to detect .pcf fonts

Tags: fonts, xset

i want to install [Profonts](http://tobiasjung.name/profont/), and it comes with .pcf (bitmap) files.

installing .tff is easy but they don't contain any bitmaps shapes so they might look not as clean as the original

i have tried to add this on fonts.conf

[image]

> ProFont

and i have tried to add the font path

```
xset fp+ /usr/local/fonts/bitmap

xset fp rehash
```

and update using:

```
fc-cache -f -v
```

but the profont still missing.

the result of fc-cache -f -v is :

> /usr/local/share/fonts/bitmap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs

no fonts found, but lot of fonts found in other directory

i use Debian 8.4 jessie, KDE 4.14.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCF fonts should go into `misc/` not `bitmap/`, I can install the fonts on that website without going through any special configuration.  I only drop the files into the correct folder.  Let's go step by step:

Get the font:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/fonts/misc
cd ~/.local/share/fonts/misc
wget -O pro.zip http://tobiasjung.name/downloadfile.php?file=profont-x11.zip
```

Place the font files directly under `~/.local/share/fonts/misc`, and, as an extra zip them to save space.

```
unzip pro.zip
mv profont-x11/P*.pcf .
for f in *.pcf; do gzip "$f"; done
```

Force a cache update (just like you are doing), and we have the fonts:

```
$ fc-cache -f
$ fc-match -a pro | grep Pro
ProFont_r400-12.pcf.gz: "ProFont" "Regular"
ProFont_r400-11.pcf.gz: "ProFont" "Regular"
ProFont_r400-15.pcf.gz: "ProFont" "Regular"
ProFont_r400-10.pcf.gz: "ProFont" "Regular"
ProFont_r400-17.pcf.gz: "ProFont" "Regular"
ProFont_r400-22.pcf.gz: "ProFont" "Regular"
ProFont_r400-29.pcf.gz: "ProFont" "Regular"
```

If you use the fontconfig defaults there is no need to tweak fonts.conf or edit the font path.

Notes:

- I'm using the local fontconfig path (`~/.local`, i.e. per user), per system path would be simply `/usr/share/fonts/misc/`.
- If you really want to use `bitmap/` instead of `misc/` you do need the `xset` call.